# Is Ubuntu compatible with the MacBook Air 1,1?

Tags: macbook-air

I have failed countless times to install this OS and I have no other means of installing it. I have tried to boot from a USB and it displayed an error saying "isolinux.bin missing or corrupt" and I have ran sudo dd on my usb about 6-8 times now with a few different versions of Ubuntu but still no progress. I don't want to have to result to using Virtual Box as I want the actual operating system to boot from. I am using refind and rEFIt as it boots as the one and I have the option to boot to the other. I have tried to use a wireless DVD drive but I found out it doesn't work and I don't have the time or money to buy a USB optical drive. Can someone please tell me if my Macbook Air is actually compatible with Ubuntu. I am running Mac OSx 10.6.8.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's compatible. You can find a HowTo [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookAir1-1/Hardy). It's quite an old guide (ubuntu 8.04) but there's no shame in trying

Answer (score 0):

ubuntu 14.14 works fine exept of the wireless network adapter, it wont be recognized. I tried the instruction with installing a broadcom driver from the bootcamp disc like described in howto from above. Didnt work. So im using a non apple usb to ethernet adapter now this works well, but still no wireless and this is a shame... dont know how to fix that, i even have the proprieatary broadcom STA driver from bcmwl-kernel-source installed. I hope so but im not the fittest in checking that..

Comment: sorry i forgot, i had the same problems booting to the usb stick. so i connected it with a usb hub this worked much better!! it recognized all the prepared sticks everytime! maybe it worth a try

Answer (score 0):

Kubuntu 17.10 working on mine, fully updated. My only serious glitch, which is fixable i think, is wake from suspend, no backlight for screen. All works but you have to look very close LOL.

I installed a prepped disc via superdrive 17.04 and then updated from:
https://mattgadient.com/2016/07/11/linux-dvd-images-and-how-to-for-32-bit-efi-macs-late-2006-models/

You want a usb wifi to get started but the firmware-b43-installer fires up the onboard adapter.

Pretty snappy on kubuntu :)

64-bit, but I formatted drive as MBR per Matt's instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install Ubuntu 20.10, Xubuntu 20.10 and Xubuntu 20.04 LTS. Because of RAM limits I will go with Xubuntu. On fresh start Xubuntu consumes 300MB of RAM.

Wi-Fi, keyboard Fn keys work just fine.

The only huge problem I have so far is sometimes some random applications crash inside the `libc` library which prevents laptop to boot. It could be related to broken HDD Samsung 80GB though. There are bad blocks there...